# Java for loop to get X

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I need help with a for loop I have for an assignment.
There is a math problem called N!, I bet some of you have heard of it. It goes like 1*2*3*4*5*n=x
I made a table like this:
1 = 1
1 * 2 = 2
1 * 2 * 3 = 6
1 * 2 * 3 * 4 = 24
1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120
1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 = 720

But I just can't seem to solve the problem. How do I get what **x** is from 1*2*3*4....*n=**x**? Here's my code so far:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\n~~Assignment 8.5~~");
    boolean go = true;

    do {
        int n;
        int total;
        System.out.println("Loop until:");
        n = input.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1;i <= n;i++)
        {

            System.out.print(i);
            if (i == n) { System.out.print(" = " + "idk" + "\n"); break;}  else { System.out.print(" * ");}
        }
    } while ( go == true);
```

Comment: Your incomplete solution is not what it is requested. A __recursive__ solution is requested. So you need a `int fact(int x)` that calculates the result by calling itself. If you use a loop to solve the problem then it's not recursion anymore. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Recursive_procedures

Comment: Indeed, there is no such thing as a recursive for loop.

Comment: My mistake, it's not suppose to be a recursion, it's just a for loop.

Comment: By the way, be careful, use BigInteger for any real world use case of this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add total calculation s
inside the for loop:

```
total *= i;
```

and after the for loop print it. Remember to initialize total with value `1`

Comment: Thank you good sir! I can't believe I missed something that simple, I feel stupid now! Thank you so much!

Comment: @PetterPettersson If this answer has helped you, don't forget to accept it.

Comment: I dont see where he is mentioning **recursion**, Anyway I just helped with his logic mistakes.

Comment: OP originally had recursion as a requirement, but he must have removed it.

Comment: Yes I changed it since I realized it was wrong. And I accepted your answer now, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the hint,

```
fact(x) = x * fact(x-1) iff x > 0
fact(x) = 1             iff x == 0
fact(x) = ERROR         iff x < 0
```

Create and implement the function `public int fact(int x)` and call it from inside a main function after picking up input from the command line or from reading user input. (and validating the input is a number)

Comment: What about `0!` ? `ERROR` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
int rec_n( int n){
    int result = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++ ){
        result *= i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ah.. however, this question is concerning java.. not javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use following Class;

```
public class RecursiveTest {

public RecursiveTest(int x){
    int i=1;
    int temptotal=1;
    while(true){
        System.out.print(i+"*");
        if(temptotal==x || temptotal>x) break;          

        temptotal=temptotal*(++i);

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
new     RecursiveTest(100);
}
```

}